# Nested Sub Assembly Finding Query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table, lets call it Assemblies. This table has items and components of those items. Further, each of those components might be listed as an item with their own components, creating a list of sub assemblies.

Here's my sql fiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec9e9/1

In this example, part A1000 contains h123, which contains T4000, which contains z123. There is another part that is not part of that assembly. Is there a way to design a query that will drill down into each sub assembly of A1000 until there are none left, without having to define how many sub assemblies are nested?

The result would look like this:

```
item    component   qty
A1000   h123        4
h123    T4000       7
T4000   z123        2
z123    f2222       4
```

omitting only what's not in the main assembly A1000

Comment: what should contain the result, how should it look?

Comment: updated op to answer your question.

Comment: Fiddle is down.  Include necessary data in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above CTE created as a function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FN_GetAssemblyChildren ( @item CHAR(30))
RETURNS  TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(

    WITH cteAssemblies (item, component, qty, AssemblyLevel)
    AS
    (   SELECT
            item, component, qty, 1
        FROM
            dbo.Assemblies b
        WHERE
            item = @item
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            e.item, e.component, e.qty, r.AssemblyLevel + 1
        FROM
            dbo.Assemblies  e
        INNER JOIN
            cteAssemblies r ON e.item = r.component
    )
    SELECT item, component, qty FROM cteAssemblies

);

GO
```

Query function

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.FN_GetAssemblyChildren ('A1000')
```

Answer (score 2):

A recursive Common Table Expression (cte) works well for something like this. 
How about this?

```
;WITH cteAssemblies (item, component, qty, AssemblyLevel)
AS
(   SELECT
        item, component, qty, 1
    FROM
        dbo.Assemblies b
    WHERE
        item = 'A1000'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        e.item, e.component, e.qty, r.AssemblyLevel + 1
    FROM
        dbo.Assemblies  e
    INNER JOIN
        cteAssemblies r ON e.item = r.component
)
SELECT item, component, qty FROM cteAssemblies
```

Comment: is this able to be used in a view?

Comment: Yes, but you can't pass parameters to a view, eg "A1000".  I can change this to a function, to which yuo can pass paramater to